# How to expose a container's mount point to the host?

Tags: docker

This is not the FAQ: "How can I mount a host directory so it is visible in the container", to which the answer is `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path`.

Instead, a special-purpose container can mount some interesting data in a mount point. How do I make the data inside that mount point visible in the host?

E.g. when running the [gluster/gluster-centos](https://hub.docker.com/r/gluster/gluster-centos) glusterfs image, the container has functionality to show and mount glusterfs data. Can I make that data visible in the host, so I don't have to install glusterfs code in my host too?

I tried to `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path` and then, from inside the container:

```
mkdir /container/path/mountpoint
mount -t glusterfs server:volume /container/path/mountpoint
```

In the container, I can see the data in the glusterfs volume under `/container/path/mountpoint`, but on the host, `/host/path/mountpoint` is present but empty. How can I expose the data in the container's `/container/path/mountpoint` to the host?

Edit: I've discovered that I can see the data inside the mount point as:

```
containerPid=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' containername)
sudo ls -l /proc/$containerPid/root/container/path/mountpoint
```

But I'm hoping for something more elegant... (And that doesn't require root to see the data)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `shared` mount flag (read about [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for more information. The following should do what you want:

```
docker run -v /host/path:/container/path:shared ...
```

E.g., if I on my host I run this (I need `--privileged` in order for `mount` to operate):

```
# mkdir /tmp/foo
# docker run -it --rm --privileged -v /tmp/foo:/foo:shared alpine sh
```

And then inside the container:

```
container# mkdir /foo/mnt
container# mount -o bind /etc /foo/mnt
```

On the host, I see:

```
# ls /tmp/foo
alpine-release  group     issue           motd        passwd     resolv.conf  ssl
apk             hostname  logrotate.d     mtab        periodic   securetty    sysctl.conf
conf.d          hosts     modprobe.d      network     profile    services     sysctl.d
crontabs        init.d    modules         opt         profile.d  shadow       udhcpd.conf
fstab           inittab   modules-load.d  os-release  protocols  shells
```

I think that reproduces exactly what you were asking about.